# Search value of a field using substring

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a project using the pages in php / mysql and html; I have a table that contains the data for calls made from a PBX and save the number called, the source, date, time, etc ... what I want to do is to search within this table all the phone numbers that have the first 4 digits equal to those that pass through the query, only that i have no idea how to pull off only the 4-digit or at least how to make a control character by character of the value contained in the field. I tell you now that the field is a varchar. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to S.O. When you signed up you acknowledged that you had read how to post. Part of that stated that you should tell us what you have tried, and that you should post when code you already have and ask us about a specific problem which you have with it. We are not a general code writing service (that isn't meant to sound snitty. If you post some code, I will gladly try to help you).

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to point out how we can help you. And if you ask good questions & we give good answers then we both help people who might have the same problem in the future. Happy overflowing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that in MySQL query, either

```
SELECT *
FROM <tablename>
WHERE LEFT(<column>, 4) = "<4 digits>"
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM <tablename>
WHERE <column> LIKE "<4 digits>%"
```

or in the PHP side :

```
if (strpos($column,'<4 digit>') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, to get substring

```
SELECT aut_name,  
RIGHT(aut_name,7)   
FROM author   
WHERE country='UK';
```

- See more at: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-right-function.php#sthash.xKNwZeki.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution: 
$variableWhereYoustoreTheFourDigits="1234"; //Use whatever you have in your code to set the value.

$result =$mysqli->query("SELECT number FROM yourtable where number LIKE \"$variableWhereYoustoreTheFourDigits%\");